# Function with extensive arguments

Tags: python

By the principle that i would like to change the function `test_var_args_call` to receive an extensive list of arguments, how i could achieve that using *args on the function?

Bellow, im sending an example of what i have so var.

```
def test_var_args_call(arg1, arg2, arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg9):
    print arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg9

args = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
test_var_args_call(*args)
```

Basicaly, instead having:

`def test_var_args_call(arg1, arg2, arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg9)`

what i would like is:

`def test_var_args_call(**args)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use one asterix and it'll work:

```
def test_var_args_call(*args):
    print args
```

or perhaps:

```
def test_var_args_call(*args):
    print ' '.join(map(str, args))
```

if you want your output to match exactly.

Comment: `print args` will print the string conversion of the list, while what I think he wants is `print ' '.join(args)`.

Comment: edited to add the conversion to string, otherwise it returns TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, int found

Comment: @Thales: Then the join makes no difference; you turned the `args` tuple into a string, then joined it (a no-op). I'll correct.

Comment: @DennisJaamann: Please stop rubberstamping invalid suggested edits. This edit was incorrect (however well-meant), the OP should have used a comment to tell me there was an additional problem instead.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Please stop rubberstamping invalid suggested edits. This edit was incorrect (however well-meant), the OP should have used a comment to tell me there was an additional problem instead.